# How to use fmap to only change the input or output type?

Tags: haskell

I am experimenting with fmap. I found examples, where you change function from `a -> a` to `Maybe a -> Maybe a` or so. I wonder how to change just input or output, for example, changing `a -> a` function to `Maybe a -> a`.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what `fmap` does. `fmap` applies a function of type `a -> b` to a value of type `t a` to convert it to `t b`, where `t` has an instance of `Functor`. It isn't meant to unwrap a layer of structure like in your example `Maybe a -> a`.

Comment: A function of type `Maybe a -> a` has to crash on input `Nothing`. Using such type is therefore a sign of bad code design. `Functor` does not allow one to craft such a function, and that's a good thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.